# required array fields with another array fields in Laravel

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5, request

I am validating two arrays in Laravel frame work. I would like to validate the relation between this two array fields. How can I validate this in request?

```
'rank.*' => 'integer|min:1|required_with:score.*',
'score.*' => 'numeric|required_with:rank.*',
```

and also, what should I do if the fields of `rank` should be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to validate the arrays themselves, and the items in the array separately. Try to write it like this:

```
[
    'rank' => 'array|required_with:score',
    'score' => 'array|required_with:rank',
    'rank.*' => 'integer|min:1',
    'score.*' => 'numeric',
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If the `rank` fields should be unique.. what shall I do?

Comment: You can use `'rank.*' => 'integer|min:1|distinct'`

Comment: Thank you a lot.. It works :) but when I write `required_with` in this way: `'score.*' => 'numeric|required_with:rank.*',`, It works better..